# Parse Server - Add Relationship in Android/Java

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

I am using the Parse Platform as a backend for my android application.

I have a database / class named 'ClassA' which contains a column relation to a class called 'Announcement'

I am trying to create an announcement and add the relation to the ClassA.

I have tired using the API reference on the official website and also code examples found on programcreek

```java
Announcement announcement = new Announcement();
announcement.setTitle(announcements_title.getText().toString());
announcement.setText(announcements_text.getText().toString());

ParseRelation<Announcement> relation = classA.getRelation("announcements");
relation.add(announcement);
classA.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
...
}
```

I am currently getting the following error message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject

But i have tried to

```java
announcement.saveInBackground();
```

before creating the relation but that is not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
ParseObject announcement = new ParseObject("Announcement");
announcement.put("title", announcements_title.getText().toString());
announcement.put("text", announcements_text.getText().toString());
announcement.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = classA.getRelation("announcements");
    relation.add(announcement);
    classA.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        ...
    });
});
```